# unique solution to system of two equations

Tags: systems-of-equations

$$\begin{cases}
ax+by=0&\\
cx+dy=0&
\end{cases}$$
How do the coefficients a, b, c and d have to be chosen for this system of equations to have one unique solution $$ \begin{cases}
x=0&\\
y=0&
\end{cases}$$?
Or what kind of conditions does one have to give to those coefficients for this system to have the unique solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the determinant of $\begin {pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end {pmatrix}$ to be nonzero to get a unique solution.  That determinant is $ad-bc$

Answer (score 2):

The solution is unique unless the two equations say the same (and there is in fact a single equation), which occurs if the coefficients are proportional.

Hence

$$\frac ac\ne\frac bd,$$ also written $$ad\ne bc.$$

(The second form is preferred, as it works even with zero coefficients.)

Answer (score 1):

Both $ax+by = 0$ and $cx+dy=0$ are straight lines passing through origin, $(0,0)$. For unique solution, these two shouldn't be coincident; their slopes should be distinct. $$-\dfrac{a}{b} \neq  -\dfrac{c}{d} $$